# Can YAML::XS honor UseAliases=0?

Tags: perl, yaml, alias

> **[UseAliases](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML#UseAliases)**
>
> YAML has an alias mechanism such that any given structure
> in memory gets serialized once. Any other references to that structure
> are serialized only as alias markers. This is how YAML can serialize
> duplicate and recursive structures.
>
> Sometimes, when you KNOW that your data is nonrecursive in nature, you
> may want to serialize such that every node is expressed in full. (ie
> as a copy of the original). Setting $YAML::UseAliases to 0 will allow
> you to do this. This also may result in faster processing because the
> lookup overhead is by bypassed.

Looking through the source for [YAML::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::XS)'s [LibYAML](https://metacpan.org/source/TINITA/YAML-LibYAML-0.81/LibYAML), it would seem (and empirical tests show) that this module does not honor `$YAML::UseAliases=0`

Is there any way to get YAML::XS to **not** dump out aliases (and instead flatten out the entire data structure)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible in YAML::XS right now.

You can create an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/ingydotnet/yaml-libyaml-pm), but no guarantee that it will be implemented ;-)